# How to hide keywords from rust-analyzer autocomplete?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, rust-analyzer

I'm using rust-analyzer 0.2.654 (latest) on VS Code 1.57.1 (also latest) on Windows 10.

The autocomplete displays all keywords, as shown below:

[image: Screenshot]

How can I hide the keywords, displaying only the actual struct members?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable this in the settings UI by navigating to `Text Editor > Suggestions > Show Keywords`:

[image]

Or alternatively disable it via `settings.json` by including:

```
"editor.suggest.showKeywords": false,
```

Comment: Wait, VS Code either suggests keywords in all contexts or not at all?  It isn’t capable of being more contextual?

Comment: @eggyal You can configure it per-language by putting it in `"[rust]": { ... }`. I don't know if there's more granular control. Rust-analyzer is already pretty contextual IMO and typically doesn't suggest irrelevant keywords. I don't know why it suggests them here.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to disable "Postfix completions" otherwise you get a load of completions like `dbg`, `match` and so on which are really automatic snippets rather than actual struct members.

[image: postfix completions]